# How to use a npm modules in nightwatchjs based project

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

Planning a nightwatchjs based project, for data driven web testing, after loading list of options from a data.json file to iterate through collections etc. I want to include underscore or lodash npm modules. I don't see a package.json where i can include dependencies to generate node_modules through npm install option.

How can one use npm modules with nightwatchjs project ?

Comment: Haven't used nightwatch, but have used mocha, and if you just create a package.json file in the directory where you're running your tests, then do an npm install, in mocha you can then simply use those packages. I would assume that since nightwatch is js, it should be the same. Just try it out.

Comment: @cargomeister sorry for late reply, I tried the way you suggested adding package.json, npm install was able to create node_modules, i was able to reference the modules using the require subsequently, thanks for a quick reply, please add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Done, and glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used nightwatch, but have used mocha, and if you just create a package.json file in the directory where you're running your tests, then do an npm install, in mocha you can then simply use those packages. I would assume that since nightwatch is js, it should be the same. Just try it out.

Comment: yes, tried, the package.json subsequent npm install making the npm modules available to use withing nightwatchjs scripts

Answer (score 0):

you may create your own using [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) specification in your project folder,

there is mine for docker:

```
{
  "name": "e2e-tests",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": { },
  "author": "Alex K",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.37.0"
    "i18n": "*", 
    "nightwatch": "0.9.21",
    "nightwatch-html-reporter": "*"
  }
```